# Test a view has rendered with spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Firstly what is the meaning behind the `render_template` method? What is a template? Is it a view? In which case, in a controller spec, does

```
response.should render_template('show')
```

Mean a request to this controller should render a view named `show.html.erb`? Or that the controller should contain this

```
render 'show'
```

So if I'm right in thinking this, which is the best way to test that view has been rendered?

**Option 1:**

```
it "should render a view" do
    response.should contain("I am the show view") # assuming the text is present in the view
end
```

**Option 2:**

```
it "should render a view" do
    response.should render_template('show')
end
```

Does **Option 2** only pass if you explicitly have `render 'show'` in your controller?

```
def create
    if params[:friend_id]

        @friend = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:friend_id])




    else

    end

    if @friend.profile_name != nil

        @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
        @user_friendship.save
        redirect_to profile_path(@friend.profile_name), status: 302

    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required!"
        redirect_to root_path, status: 302
    end 
end
```

When testing the `create` action with a valid request, the `profile_path` does indeed lead to the show view, but is this out of the scope of the spec? I get this error you see:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template('show')
   expecting <"show"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Or another way?

Also, in order to use methods such as `contain` in an rspec test, does a headless server such as `capybara-webkit`, or a headed sever such as the `selinium-webdriver` need to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not want to test this in one test. You will find yourself 'fixing' tests allover the place when you decide to change the flow of the application.

Use separate tests:

- Test create request is redirected to the profile_path
- Test if the profile_path renders "show"

Example:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  it "should redirect to profile_path" do
    post 'create', valid_params
    response.should redirect_to profile_path
  end
end

describe "GET #show" do
  it "should render show template" do
    get 'show', valid_params 
    response.should render_template('show')
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. And render_template means render view?

Comment: It will check if the show template will be rendered. It does not actually render the page, so there might be something wrong on the page itself. If you want to test that, please use the view specs. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec